# Question on a mixed-norm estimate

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, inequalities, schrodinger-operators

---

I am currently reading the paper [*Global existence and scattering for rough solutions to generalized nonlinear Schrödinger equations on $\mathbb{R}$*](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=&s5=Global%20existence%20and%20scattering%20for%20rough%20solutions%20to%20generalized%20nonlinear%20Schr%C3%B6dinger%20equations&s6=&s7=&s8=All&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq) by Colliander, Holmer, Visan, Zhang. In this article, they study the solution to the following equation,
\begin{aligned}
\begin{cases}
i\partial_t u + \Delta u = |u|^{2p}u, \quad p>0 \\
u(0, x)=u_0(x). 
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
I am trying to understand how they arrive at the following inequality for the mixed-norms of the solution $u$ on page 476:
\begin{aligned}
\|u^{2p}\|_{L^2_t L^1_x} \lesssim \|u\|^{\varepsilon}_{L^8_{t, x}} \|u\|^{2p-\varepsilon}_{L^{p_\varepsilon}_t L^{q_\varepsilon}_x},
\end{aligned}
with $p_\varepsilon =\frac{8(2p-\varepsilon)}{4-\varepsilon}$, $q_\varepsilon =\frac{8(2p-\varepsilon)}{8-\varepsilon}$ and
$$\|u\|_{L^p_t, L^q_x} \equiv \left(\int_{I}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} |u|^q\,dx\right)^{p/q}\,dt\right)^{1/p}$$
with $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ a finite interval. I suspect that this is an application of Hölder's inequality, but was not able to find the correct use of the latter.